# What's the meaning of "$" in the symbol "_creat$NOCANCEL"?

Tags: c

I got the output in terminal when I run the command 
`nm -gU /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib`:

```
000000000007cb4c T ___opendir2
000000000002a944 T ___opendir2$INODE64
00000000000141d0 T ___ovfl_delete


000000000003a9e1 T _fdopen
000000000007af54 T _fdopen$DARWIN_EXTSN
```

1. What's the meaning of `$` in `___opendir2$INODE64`?
2. What's the meaning of `INODE64` in `___opendir2$INODE64`?

When looking at the symbols of `libdispatch`(Apple grand central dispatch): [libdispatch symbols](https://ios.ddf.net/symbols/D1654155-0D40-3E77-967B-D529061C87A4), I found three symbols with the same prefix: `_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF`

```
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81
```

3. Are these three symbols generated by the same source?

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular meaning. The dollar sign counts as a letter in linker symbols (just like an underscore does), so they are just symbols someone has chosen to name that way. Probably they deliberately chose to include a dollar sign to reduce the risk of colliding with something that the programmer could have defined in C.

Comment: In fact I don't think *linkers* care much about which characters are used in symbols at all, but *assemblers* typically allow writing `$` in symbol names out of the box, so it is often used to create symbols that can't clash with those of a C program, or other higher level languages.

Comment: This only answers one of OP’s question — arguably more interesting is the question about the name mangling on display here.

Comment: @HenningMakholm "An assembler is a type of computer program that interprets software programs written in assembly language into machine language, code and instructions that can be executed by a computer." I think that the assembler is associated with assembly language not the c language. https://www.techopedia.com/definition/3971/assembler

Comment: @Viton, correct. So the object file you're looking at was probably not produced from C source, but from a hand-written assembly source. (That doesn't mean the object file can't be designed to be *used* by C code).

Comment: @HenningMakholm how come they can't clash with C symbols? though not exactly standard, many (most?) C compilers allow `$` in identifiers. In fact, those identifiers are defined at C preprocessor level, look [here](https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/a449c6a3b8014d9406c2ddbdc81795da24aa7443/bsd/sys/cdefs.h#L675).

Comment: Correction to my last sentence: the `$` is used in a string literal there, but those aliases/symbols are still callable from `C`.

Comment: @mosvy: The point is that they're not part of the namespace a C programmer rightly feels is his to define names in.

Comment: Right, I was commenting on your 1st comment, not on the answer, which is OK.